# React Swiper.js Deleting slide at index rendered from array

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I can't seem to figure out how to delete a slide at the current index which is rendered from an array using Swiper.js. [Code Sandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-remove-slides-w4gy3?file=/src/App.js).

I have tried:

```
function deleteSlide() {
    swiper.current.swiper.removeSlide(currentIndex);
    var temp = slides;
    temp.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    setSlides(temp);
}
```

But the problem is that it does a double delete when the state updates. If I only run `removeSlide`, it removes the slide but my array is not updated. If I do anything else, my array updates but the slides don't update until I do a swipe. Adding slides to the end of the array so far works fine.

Without explicitly calling `removeSlide`, I tried the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    swiper.current.swiper.update();
}, [slides]);
```

But I'm not quite sure why this isn't actually updating the Swiper instance, [according to the docs that's what I believe it should be doing](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#methods-and-properties). I recognize that this isn't being called when the state updates in `deleteSlide` either, and I'm not entirely sure why.

The ideal behavior is that the current view stays put, and when the current slide is deleted, the slide at `index + 1` slides into position. If you delete the very last slide, then you slide to the 2nd last slide and the last slide gets deleted. I can take care of this as long as I can actually update the Swiper instance correctly.

How should I go about this? Appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this:

```
function deleteSlide() {
    var temp = [...slides];
    temp.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    setSlides(temp);
}
```

Just had to use the spread `...` operator to copy the array correctly. Although it is worth noting that this resets the state for all the other rendered slides, I need to figure out how to fix that.

EDIT: [Updated Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-remove-slides-w4gy3?file=/src/App.js). To prevent re-rendering of all other array elements, the key of each element must be unique across renders. Fixed by setting the key to be a count, which is strictly increasing.